# Limit of products

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n} \right)...\left(1+\frac{n}{n} \right )}}$$

I thought this was linked to Riemann sums, yet I could not construct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)^{1/n}$$

$$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)\right) = \exp\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)\right)$$

$\Delta_x = \frac{1}{n}$ and $x_i = \frac{i}{n}$. $\Delta_x$ goes to $0$ in the limit and $x_1$ goes to $0$ and $x_n$ goes to $1$ in the limit.

$$L = \exp\left(\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x) dx\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $$g(n) = \left( \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 + \tfrac{k}{n}\right)\right)^{1/n},$$ and consider the logarithm $$\log g(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right).$$  Now show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \log g(n)$ is a Riemann sum with an appropriate choice of function and interval of integration.