# interesting algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if the equation $AB +5I_n = 3A + 2B$    holds then which is affirmation is true :

a ) $ A -2I_n$ is invertible

b)$B-3I_n$ is invertible

PS : I  don't understand where to even begin with this problem

Comment: "I have no clue" questions are not well received here.

Comment: Invertible means the determinant is non-zero. Use this fact. Note that (a-2)(b-3) = ab - 2b - 3a + 5. Commutativity of matrix multiplication is important

Comment: but since i dont know how to start this problem i kinda need someone to explain it dont i ?

Comment: Strat by writing down the definition of invertibility for $A-2I_n$. Look up the determinant. One can always try something. Start doing it! Also the title is not good. You have tried more for your [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359213/limit-of-a-weird-series).

Comment: If you don't understand the question, go back and ask about the definitions and concepts required to do so. Just throwing up a question and saying "I have no idea" makes it pointless to both the community and to you.

Answer (score -1):

As elaborated in the comment, consider $$(A-2I)(B-3I)=AB-3A-2B+6I=(?)$$ Then what can you say about $A-2I$ and $B-3I$? (There is nothing to do with the determinants here!)

One more interesting question, can you use this to show that $AB=BA$?